# redundant transaction ids, while matching various patterns in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VQ2bzoTkUEG2v4JYUlEdzM-JsYHt4IVA/view?usp=sharing), which represents a database of subgraphs (n = 15291). Each subgraph has unique id that starts with 't #'.

I would like to retrieve transactions that match following patterns:

> pattern 1:'u 0 1 2', 'u 0 2 2', 'u 1 2 2'
>
> pattern 2: 'u 0 1 2', 'u 0 2 2', 'u 0 3 3'
>
> pattern 3: 'u 0 1 2', 'u 0 2 2', 'u 1 3 2'
>
> pattern 4: 'u 0 1 2', 'u 0 3 2', 'u 1 2 2'

I have this piece of code to run various patterns. For example, this code runs pattern 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = shift @ARGV or die $!;

open (my $fh, '<', $input) or die $!;

my ($transaction_id, $edge_1, $edge_2, $edge_3);

while (<$fh>) {
  if (m/^(t\h*#\h*[0-9,\h-]+)/) {
    $transaction_id = $1;
  } elsif (m/^(u\h+[0]\h+[1]\h+[2])/) {
    $edge_1 = $1;
  } elsif (m/^(u\h+[0]\h+[2]\h+[2])/) {
    $edge_2 = $1;
  } elsif (m/^(u\h+[1]\h+[2]\h+[2])/) {
    $edge_3 = $1;
  }

  if ($transaction_id and $edge_1 and $edge_2 and $edge_3) {
    print "$transaction_id\t$edge_1\t$edge_2\t$edge_3\n";
    ($transaction_id, $edge_1, $edge_2, $edge_3) = (undef) x 4;
  }
}
```

However, when I modify it to the pattern 4, I got redundant ids with pattern 1. For example, while searching for pattern 4, I obtained transaction `t # 3-99, 1 u 0 1 2 u 0 3 2 u 1 2 2`. Similarly, while searching for pattern 1, I obtained the same transaction `t # 3-99, 1 u 0 1 2    u 0 2 2 u 1 2 2`. My understanding that all four groups share unique ids and should sum up to 15291 (# of transactions in DB).

I tried to modify code, but I was unsuccessful. I checked all of the proposed solutions from my previous two questions, but I run into the same problem.

I would highly appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Olha

Comment: Are you saying that these different patterns may come with the same ID?  (Or that these four actually always have the same ID?)  If data is indeed like that then why is that a problem -- what do you want to do with/about it?

Comment: Please provide sample data that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Early in the question it says that "_Each subgraph has unique id_" -- but then `t # 3-99, 1` is shown to come up twice, with different patterns, so clearly isn't unique -- or do you mean to say that that is an error? Are ID's unique or do different pattern (nay) have the same ones?

Comment: um, right, `t # 3-99, 1` doesn't repeat in the file you linked. So I don't get the statement -- that the shown code is wrong?

Comment: The code assigns different pattern to the same transaction and I am not sure why. Every transaction is unique, so it should match only to one pattern. In case of t # 3-99 it should match to pattern 4, but not pattern 1.

Comment: @OlhaKholod "_Every transaction is unique, so it should match only to one pattern_" -- ah, OK. Then the code is wrong in some way, no?  I used my program from your previous question, resulting in 15290 lines of output.  Then I use `grep` on the command line to filter that output as you ask here, and for pattern 1 (`prog file | grep 'u 0 1 2 u 0 2 2 u 1 2 2'`), as well as for pattern 4, I get ten (10) lines, with clearly distinct `t`-IDs.   (That filtering from the command-line, using system's `grep`, can -- and should -- be added to that program, using Perl's facilities, which is easy to do.)

Comment: Wait -- but regex here don't attempt to match the whole patterns you show.  For example, the first `elsif` branch matches simply on `u 0 1 2` -- anywhere on the line and regardless of what else is there (and happens to match all four patterns you want). So it scoops up a lot more than the specific four patterns you want.  That's the problem will all that regex in a long `if` branch -- now you have to change all of it

Comment: Thank you so much, @zdim. Your solution works perfectly. I was able to retrieve non-redundant ids for each pattern and they sum up to 15290, which I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very well articulated by OP.

It would be better to provide file with data and a few samples of desired transactions for output.

In hope that the problem was properly understood the following piece of code is written

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $fname = shift or die 'Provide filename';

my $skip = qr/^v \d+ \d+/;
my $data = qr/^u \d+ \d+ \d+/;
my $tran = qr/^t # \d-\d+, \d/;

my $pattern_1 = qr/u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 2 2/;
my $pattern_2 = qr/u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 0 3 3/;
my $pattern_3 = qr/u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2/;
my $pattern_4 = qr/u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2/;

my @array;

open my $fh, '<', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname";
    
my $line = <$fh>;

$line =~ s/(\r|\n)//;    # chop off eol

while( <$fh> ) {
    next if /$skip/;
    s/(\r|\n)//;         # chop off eol
    $line .= '  ' . $_ if /$data/;
    if( /$tran/ ) {
        push @array, $line;
        $line = $_;
    }   
}

push @array, $line;

close $fh;

/$pattern_1|$pattern_2|$pattern_3|$pattern_4/ && say for @array;
```

Output

```
t # 3-0, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-3, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-5, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-6, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-7, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-8, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-9, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-10, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-99, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-100, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-139, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-140, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-141, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-142, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-143, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-146, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-147, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-214, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-278, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-296, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-297, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-314, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-324, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-481, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-482, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-483, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-484, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-485, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-486, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-487, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-498, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-499, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-500, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-501, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-542, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-729, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-730, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-731, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-732, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-733, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-734, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-735, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-736, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-737, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-738, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-739, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-740, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-742, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-743, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-744, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-745, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-746, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-772, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-774, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-775, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-776, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-777, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-778, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-779, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-781, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-782, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-783, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-785, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-786, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-793, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-842, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-849, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-852, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-853, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-856, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-857, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-859, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-860, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-861, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-862, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-863, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-864, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-866, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-867, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-868, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-869, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-872, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-873, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-874, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-875, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-876, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-877, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-878, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-879, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-880, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-881, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-882, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-883, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-887, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-888, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-906, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-907, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-908, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-909, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-911, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-912, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-916, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-919, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-920, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-927, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-929, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-932, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-934, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-935, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-936, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-937, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-957, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-960, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-961, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-973, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-990, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-991, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-992, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-993, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-994, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1076, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1077, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1102, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1103, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1104, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1106, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1108, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1109, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1110, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1111, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1112, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1113, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1114, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1115, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1124, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1125, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1126, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1127, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1128, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1191, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1209, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1210, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1211, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1212, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1213, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1214, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1286, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1287, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1356, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1360, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1362, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1363, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1365, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1366, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1367, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1368, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1369, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1370, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1371, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1372, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1374, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1380, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1382, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1383, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1384, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1385, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1386, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1387, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1388, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1389, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1391, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1393, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1400, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1434, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1675, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1676, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1677, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1679, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1732, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1733, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1734, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1745, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1746, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1757, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1765, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1774, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1776, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1777, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1780, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1781, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1782, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1849, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1850, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1851, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1852, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-1889, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1890, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1891, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1892, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1894, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-1944, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2054, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2134, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2135, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2145, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2146, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2147, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2202, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2203, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2204, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2276, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2277, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2279, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2282, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2283, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2284, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2285, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2287, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2304, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2305, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2306, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2307, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2308, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2309, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2310, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2311, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2312, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2313, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2318, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2319, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2320, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2336, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2363, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2364, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2386, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2391, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2453, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2454, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2455, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2456, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2457, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2458, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2459, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2460, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2461, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2462, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2463, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2464, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2465, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2476, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2531, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2533, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2534, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2535, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2536, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2573, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2574, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2575, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2655, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2707, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2730, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2751, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2762, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2767, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2768, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2773, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2776, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2787, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2788, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2801, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2810, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2829, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2831, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2832, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2833, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-2874, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-2875, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3250, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3251, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3426, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3436, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3438, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3443, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3444, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3445, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3449, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3450, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3451, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3452, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3725, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3791, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-3793, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-3794, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-3795, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-3796, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-3797, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-3809, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3814, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3815, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3817, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3820, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3821, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3822, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3823, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3824, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3825, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3826, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3827, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3829, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3830, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3831, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3832, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3833, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3834, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3835, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3836, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3837, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3842, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3849, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3850, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3851, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3852, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3853, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3854, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3855, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3856, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3857, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3893, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-3898, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-3901, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3906, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-3910, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-3941, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4029, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4087, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4124, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4175, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4342, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4394, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4437, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4438, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4439, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4440, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4442, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4443, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4444, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4463, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4469, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4470, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4471, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4472, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4473, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4474, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4478, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4479, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4480, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4481, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4494, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4495, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4504, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4508, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4524, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4525, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4526, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4527, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4569, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4570, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4571, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4663, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4664, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4665, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4668, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4670, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4671, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4674, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4675, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4676, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4677, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4678, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4679, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4680, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4681, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4682, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4683, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4684, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4688, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4716, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4721, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4724, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4727, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4733, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4734, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4736, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4737, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4739, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4740, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4741, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4742, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4746, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4749, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4750, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4751, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4752, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4753, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4754, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4755, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4756, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4805, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4837, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4848, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4852, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4923, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4925, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4937, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4938, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4939, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4941, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4942, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4944, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4946, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4947, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4955, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4956, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-4957, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4958, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4959, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4961, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4962, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-4971, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-5079, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-5103, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-5126, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-5247, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-5296, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
........
t # 3-13088, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13095, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13134, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13135, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13238, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13327, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13460, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13532, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13533, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13534, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13535, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13536, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13537, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13538, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13552, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13553, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13554, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13555, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13556, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13557, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13558, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13559, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13560, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13561, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13562, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13563, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13564, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13565, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13566, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13569, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13599, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13600, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13601, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13602, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13603, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13604, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13619, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13620, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13621, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13636, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13637, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13646, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13649, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13650, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13678, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13725, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13732, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13733, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13737, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13740, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13741, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13742, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13743, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13744, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13745, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13756, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13757, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13772, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13780, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13781, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13782, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13783, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13787, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13789, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13790, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13792, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13793, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13794, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13796, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13835, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13836, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13837, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13838, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13839, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13840, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13841, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13842, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13846, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13851, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13852, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13853, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13855, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13857, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13858, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13861, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13862, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13866, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13867, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13868, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13869, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13870, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13871, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13872, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13873, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13874, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13875, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13877, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13886, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13887, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13888, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13892, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13900, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13901, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13906, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-13987, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13988, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13990, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13992, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13994, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-13998, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14024, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14025, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14158, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14159, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14160, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14161, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14162, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14163, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14164, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14165, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14167, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14168, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14183, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14184, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14190, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14191, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14192, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14193, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14194, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14195, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14196, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14197, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14198, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14199, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14200, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14201, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14202, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14251, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14252, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14253, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14254, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14255, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14256, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14257, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14258, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14266, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-14286, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14287, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14288, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14289, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14291, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14292, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14293, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14294, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14295, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14296, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14297, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14302, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14304, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14305, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14306, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14312, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14314, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14316, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14317, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14318, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14319, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14320, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14405, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-14444, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-14585, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-14590, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14591, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14592, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14593, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14594, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14595, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14596, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14597, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14598, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14599, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14600, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14612, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14613, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14615, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14618, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14619, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14620, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-14678, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-14691, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-14692, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-14785, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-15110, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-15135, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-15151, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-15158, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-15159, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-15160, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-15174, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-15175, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-15189, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-15203, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-15204, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-15205, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-15222, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-15274, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
t # 3-15283, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 2 2  u 1 3 2
t # 3-15288, 1  u 0 1 2  u 0 3 2  u 1 2 2
```